# Function for happy algorithm not recurring properly

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am having trouble with my happy algorithm. The algorithm takes an input which came from my html input box. It squares the digits and adds them up. If the sum is 1, then the number is happy but if not, it checks against all of the previous sums to see if it is the same as  one of them. If so, the number is unhappy. If neither then the algorithm is repeated with the new number.

```
 //takes input value and then receives the output
    function start() {
      var int = document.getElementById('inp').value;
      numbersChecked = [];
      var value = happy(int);
    
      console.log(int.toString() + " is " + value);
    }
    //recurs the funtion it doesn't work with it in the function
    function unhappy(n) {
      happy(n)
    }
    //the main function. Takes the value, adds up the squares of their digits and then checks
    //to see if it is equal to one (happy) or repeats a numbers (unhappy)
    function happy(n) {
      n.toString();
      //create|reset variables
      sum = 0;
      //loop through digits in string
      for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        num = parseInt(n[i]);
        square = num**2;
        sum+=square;
      }
      //check numbers for repeats or return "Happy"
      if (sum == 1) {
        return "Happy";
      } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < numbersChecked.length; i++) {
          if (sum == numbersChecked[i]) {
            return "Unhappy";
          }
        }
        numbersChecked.push(sum);
        console.log(numbersChecked);
        unhappy(sum);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide *sample input* where it is not working properly?

Comment: Dont worry, i fixed it. it was about converting between strings and integers